# Create sparse matrix with more than 2^31-1 non-zero elements

Tags: r, memory, matrix, sparse-matrix, rcpp

I am creating a sparse matrix using vectors longer than 2^31 elements. See sample code below:

```
library(Matrix)

sz=2^31+10000
a=sample.int(15000000,size=sz,replace=TRUE)
b=sample.int(25000,size=sz,replace=TRUE)
c=sparseMatrix(a,b)
```

This gives me the error on the final line:

> Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) :  long vectors not
>   supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:137

How do I resolve this issue? Is it not possible to create a sparse matrix with so many non-zero entries? I have used the latest libraries available and I have lots of memory available. 128GB RAM to be exact.

Comment: Please do not cross-post as you [already opened an issue ticket](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/337).

Comment: Dirk, this question is more of a how to on creating the matrix of more than 2^31 elements - I understand it is not an rcpp issue.